# Android app licensing new and old - doubts

Tags: android, public-key-encryption, android-lvl

Just few weeks ago Google changed Android LVL API (License Verification Library).

In old LVL license checking was based on license verification using public/private keys generated on per account base. New one suppose to use public/private keys per application base.

I have application which uses old LVL and looks like that it works (looks like, but in fact I don't know). Application embeds public key generated on per account base.

Now what should I supposed to do when I will decide to upgrade my app? Embed public key for application or still use public key for account?

I didn't manage to find any clues on Google's Android developer site...

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. My app gets a NOT LICENSED response when I use the License Key generated for the specific app. However, when I use the old License Key (which was generated per-account, not per-app) it works as supposed. I'm using the latest version of the com.google.android.vending.licensing SDK.

Comment: The instructions on Google's Android Developer site seems to be outdated - it references the LVL as Google Market Licensing. As we all know, Google changed from "Market" to "Play" 9 months ago...

Comment: Oh well, seems you just have to go get a cup of coffee and wait 30 minutes or so when creating a new license key. Test responses now work as expected with the newly generated key as well.

Comment: The old setup is still working for me as well. I haven't received any notices from Google that something has to be done here, and normally they would, like they did with the copy protection which they are supposed to remove soon.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to think of the old license key system as deprecated - it still works on old apps, and may continue to work for updates. As with anything that is deprecated and can be disable or removed at any time in the future without further notice, you might not want to wait too long to use the new system - but your old keys should work for now. So if you have to push out an update you might be ok with the old system/keys.

As BadCash suggested, the new license key generation does not yet appear to be an instant process. Once generated it can take anywhere from minutes to a few hours to propagate across their licensing system so it can be recognized as a valid licensing signature.

Please note that Google appears to be moving away from this system entirely, however, as per their site: [Google Play Licensing Service](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/186113?hl=en)

So I would suggest resigning with the new system to avoid future annoyance - if it isn't too much hassle, depending on your number of apps - and sit comfortably knowing that in the future you won't have to do it again at all.